# Minimum length of a nontrivial word in $[[F_n,F_n],F_n]$

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $F_n$ be the free group on $n$ generators.  I would like to know what the minimum length of a nontrivial word in the third term in the lower central series of $F_n$ is - (i.e. $[[F_n,F_n],F_n]$).

I know that since the exponent sum must be even, and length has the same parity as exponent sum, the length must be even.  I know that it can not be less than 4 and with some simple guessing I can get elements of length 8.  Could I ever find elements of length 6 or 4?

Comment: Isn't it $0$ since $[[1,1],1] = 1$?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Sorry - I intended to say nontrivial - I edited

Comment: The only reduced words pf length $4$ with zero exponent sum are commutators of the generators, so you can eliminate length $4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no such elements of length $4$ or $6$.

As I said in my comment, the only length $4$ word in $\gamma_2(F_n) = [F_n,F_n]$ is $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ where $a^{\pm 1}$ and $b^{\pm 1}$ are free generators, and that does not lie in $\gamma_3(F_n)$.

By considering cyclic conjugates, we can see that the only essentially distinct words of reduced length $6$ in $\gamma_2(F_n)$ are $a^2ba^{-2}b^{-1}$, $aba^{-1}cb^{-1}c^{-1}$, and $abca^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-1}$, where $c^{\pm 1}$ is a third free generator.

The first of these does not lie in $\gamma_3(P)=1$ in the finite  order $27$ quotient $\langle a,b \mid a^{9}=b^3=1, a^b=a^4 \rangle$ $P$ of $F_n$, so it does not lie in $\gamma_3(F_n)$.

For the other two words, we can consider their images in the quotient of $H = \langle a,b,c,\ldots \mid b=c \rangle$ of $F_n$, which is free of rank $n-1$, and we get the words
$aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ and $ab^2a^{-1}b^{-2}$, neither of which lie in $\gamma_3(H)$.

So there are no words of length less than $8$ in $\gamma_3(F_n)$. Of course this type or argument will only work in relatively straightforward examples. I don't know how you would go about finding the minimal length of a word in $\gamma_k(F_n)$ for higher values of $k$.

Comment: Thank you for this - I suppose we also have the word $abcb^{-1}a^{-1}c^{-1}$ but that is handled by your argument above.  Is there any trick with coming up with these finite groups or is it magic :-)?

Comment: Yes $abcb^{-1}a^{-1}c^{-1}$ is a cyclic conjugate of $bcb^{-1}a^{-1}c^{-1}a$, which is just a relabelling of $aba^{-1}cb^{-1}c^{-1}$. There is no trick, and this kind of reasoning would get probably exponentially more difficult as the words got longer, which is why I think you would need a different method for more difficult problems of this type.

Comment: Ahh ok yes sorry I missed that.  I suppose that the Magnus representation also allows you to compute how far down in the lower central series you are for a given element.